# How to cut/get all patterns of RE from one line

Tags: regex, grep, cut

How does one get all instances, and only the instances of a regular expression contained within a single line or string?

For example, suppose the output (all one single line) from a webpage is:

```
<Table border=1 cellpadding=2><TR><TH><font size=2>LAN IP BLOCK</font></TH><TH><font size=2>CUST_NAME</font></TH> <TH><font size=2>ID
</TH></TR><TR><TD><font size=2>10.4.4.0 / 29</font></TD><TD><font size=2>Customer data</font></TD><TD><font size=2></font></TD></T
TD><font size=2>10.1.1.0 / 27</font></TD><TD><font size=2>Customer</font></TD><TD><font size=2></font></TD></TR></Table><p>
```

I'd like to get every instance of the IP CIDR data.  I know I've have to use an IP address RE (and I believe I can figure/find that out), but how do I get EACH instance and remove all other text simply?  I'd like to do this on the command line with grep/sed etc. but thinking I need to use python.  I know I could use Perl but I'd have to get that installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `grep` options `-o` and `-E` are what you are looking for:

```
grep -oE "pattern1|pattern2|pattern3|pattern4|...|patternN" input_file
```

From `man grep`:

```
 -o, --only-matching
      Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line,
      with each such part on a separate output line.

 -E, --extended-regexp
      Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression
      (-E is specified by POSIX.)
```